# How to connect two tables when one table can have multiple data for one user (multiple phone no, for one user),to be shown in one row

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have one table that contains (user_id (primary key), first_name, last_name, email, phone number) and another that contains (phone_id(primary key), phone_number2 and a foreign key user_id).

One user can have multiple phone numbers.

So using the query:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM personal LEFT JOIN phone ON personal.user_id = phone.user_id";
```

I can show the data in a table.

My problem is that if one person have multiple phone numbers it will be shown in a new row for each additional phone number.

How can I combine all of the additional phone numbers in one row. Mind the phone numbers are entered dynamically with jQuery so one user might have a second phone number or not.

Afterwards I need to be able to edit that data.

php code for entry form data

```
// Makes connection to the database
$mysqli = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die($mysqli->error);

// Checks if the submit button has been pressed, setst the variable values of the name values from the form
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
// Inserts the form input into the personal table in the exercise database
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO personal (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone_number')")
      OR die($mysqli->error);
  $user_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
// Checks if the Add more numbers button has been pressed
 if (isset($_POST['phone_number2'])) {
   $phone_number2 = $_POST['phone_number2'];
// foreach statement to loop trought the array of inserted additional phone numbers
  foreach ($phone_number2 as $key => $value) {
      $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO phone (user_id, phone_number2) VALUES('$user_id','$value')")
               OR die($mysqli->error);
}
}
}
```

the html and php code that present the entry data:

```
<?php
  require_once 'process.php';

    $result = "SELECT * FROM personal LEFT JOIN phone ON personal.user_id = phone.user_id";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr class="thead-dark">
  <th>First name</th>
  <th>Last name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Phone number</th>
  <th>Additional phone numbers</th>
  <th colspan=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["phone_number"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["phone_number2"];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php
    }
  };
 ?>
```

Comment: with _"in one row"_ do you mean a table-row or a dataset-row? If the first one: please show how you display them now!

Comment: In the link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/83121f00zzaxmll/example.png?dl=0) is the result that im getting. I want all the addtitional phone numbers to be in one one <td> now each in a new row with the first name, last name and email repeating all the time.

Comment: please show the code that produces this. It's a matter of checking wheater you have a new person -> then make new row and show Name, etc - if not show the (now new) phonenumber as new column.

Comment: Edited question posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by with group_concat(), so you query can be for html and php code will


$result = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, group_concat(phone_number2) as phone_number2 FROM personal LEFT JOIN phone ON personal.user_id = phone.user_id group by phone.user_id,first_name, last_name, email, phone_number"

if you are using mariadb then group by phone.user_id only will be enough.

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you. The problem now is that with each new entry the header row is repeated, link with the picture in addition. How can i avoid that? (https://www.dropbox.com/s/83121f00zzaxmll/example.png?dl=0)

Comment: `code`
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr class="thead-dark">
<th>First name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone number</th>
<th>Additional phone numbers</th>
<th colspan=""></td>
</tr>
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["first_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["phone_number"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["phone_number2"];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
</div>
`code`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance